# DB2/IDAA: How to properly format VARCHAR to TIMESTAMP with milliseconds

Tags: database, db2, db2-zos

I am using IDAA for DB2.  At one point I use TO_DATE to convert some dates and it works:

`TO_DATE('09/03/2018 06:49:23','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')`

But when I have a VARCHAR value with milliseconds in the timestamp, TO_DATE returns an error.  I looked around online and found an answer that says to use TO_TIMESTAMP but that doesn't work:

`TO_TIMESTAMP('09/03/2018 06:49:23.443000','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.NNNNNN')`

I've looked at every answer on here and tried many variations.  I've tried every combination of the functions TO_TIMESTAMP, TO_DATE, TIMESTAMP_FORMAT and the format for milliseconds as FF, FF6, NNNNNN.  I get these errors:

`NO AUTHORIZED FUNCTION NAMED TO_TIMESTAMP HAVING COMPATIBLE ARGUMENTS WAS FOUND. SQLCODE=-440`

`SQL error: SQLCODE = -904, SQLSTATE = 57011, SQLERRMC =   Invalid Date.. SQLCODE=-904`

Maybe it's different for the IDAA? I don't know.

I'm running DB2 for z/OS V11 using IBM Data Studio 4.1.3.

Comment: What happens when you call `TO_TIMESTAMP('09/03/2018 06:49:23','MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')` ?  Do you still get the same error message?  Can you include the full SQL code in which the call to `TO_TIMESTAMP` appears?

Comment: It still doesn't recognize TO_TIMESTAMP as a function, but that works with TO_DATE.  That's the only line of code in the SELECT.

Comment: My gut feeling is that your DB2 installation has some sort of problem.  Your code looks like it should work, at least according to IBM's documentation for `TO_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Please EDIT your question to specify the Db2 server platform (z/OS, i-series, Linux/Unix/Windows), and its version + fixpack.

Comment: There's no `TO_TIMESTAMP` function in Db2 for z/OS. `TO_DATE` and `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` both should work. May be you have some other whitespace character instead of ASCII space (`0x20`) in your input string.

Answer (score 0):

`TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` for Db2 for z/OS is documented here

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_timestampformat.html

Do note that `HH` is the same as `HH12`, not `HH24`, so it might be that you need, e.g.

```
$ db2 "values TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('09/03/2018 16:49:23','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')"

1                         
--------------------------
2018-09-03-16.49.23.000000

  1 record(s) selected.
```

( The above is from Db2 LUW, but I would assume that function works the same on Db2 for z/OS/ and DAA )

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following link - 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4LQ8_4.1.0/com.ibm.datatools.aqt.doc/gui/concepts/c_idaa_inconsistencies.html

IBM Db2 Analytics Accelerator for z/OS does not support all date and time formats that Db2 supports. This might lead to different results for accelerated and inhouse Db2 queries if the VARCHAR_FORMAT or TIMESTAMP_FORMAT scalar function is used. The following formats are not supported by IBM Db2 Analytics Accelerator for z/OS:

```
FF[n] - fractional seconds (000000-999999)

The optional number n is used to specify the number of digits to include in the return value. Valid values for n are the integers from 1-6. The default is 6.
ID - ISO day of the week (1-7)

The value 1 represents Monday. The value 7 represents Sunday.
IYYY - ISO year (0000-9999)

The last four digits of the year based on the ISO week that is returned.
NNNNNN - microseconds (000000-999999)

This format is equivalent to FF6.
RR - last two digits of the year (00-99)
SSSSS - seconds since the previous midnight
```